# Are there other peaceful enclaves in the world like in Baerle-Nassau (Belgium/Nederlands)?

Tags: borders, netherlands, belgium, landmarks, geography

I recently discovered this very interesting geographical singularity in The Netherlands (or Belgium depending on how you see it) in [Baerle-Nassau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Nassau#Netherlands_enclaves).

[image: Baerle Nassau]

Inside the Netherlands you can find a portion of Belgium, with all its rights and duties. But most amazing even, you  get Nederlands again inside Belgium...  (or Belgium surrounding... depending on how you look at it). Almost a country Matrioska. You can check in [google maps](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Baarle-Nassau/@51.4376118,4.9540996,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47c6a5342570ab1d:0x808696d1e9939744) as well.

[image: Baerle-Nassau]

There are a few enclaves all over the world, for many reasons, but not so many peaceful and with this charecteristics I assume. I was wondering:

**Are there other peaceful enclaves in the world, like in Baerle-Nassau, that the Netherlands and Belgium have, that can be visited?**

Comment: What characteristics are you looking for, exactly? Enclave-inside-enclave? Inconspicuous border running through an inhabited area? The latter, but only for enclaves? Something else?

Comment: @chirlu both preferably, or one of them, but only for enclaves.

Comment: Wikipedia has a very comprehensive [List of enclaves and exclaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_enclaves_and_exclaves) which you might find interesting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a geography trivia question doesn't become a travel question just by adding "and can I travel there."

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry David but they do. There are many questions that become travel questions because you want to travel there. We have all kind of examples in travelSE. E.g.: We have many questions on medical care. Plus geography is definitely a very important part o travelling.

Comment: @nsn OK. So, I guess all the other Stack Exchange sites are redundant then. Got a science question? Just add "Oh, er, and can I travel to the lab where it was discovered?" and post to Travel! History question? Travel there! Programming question? Do it on your laptop on the move and post it to Travel! In fact, that would literally be a [boat programming question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/276803): a question that's really about some other subject but which is asserted to be on-topic because the asker added some trivial connection to the subject of the Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DavidRicherby there are definitely overlaps. It's not the first time we transfer questions to another SE or questions are transferred here. It only depends on which comunity can answer your question best.